# What is the correct derivation for the Rotation Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations, robotics

This might seem like a basic question, but I've been stuck on this for a bit.

Upon looking at many different sources, I found 2 derivations of the rotation matrix.

1. [One of them](https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/rotation-matrix/) considers a point at a distance of r from the
   origin and rotates it by a certain angle theta and derives the
   matrix by comparing the projections of the original point and the
   new, rotated point.
2. [The other one](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html) considers coordinate axes of unit length which
   are rotated by a certain angle theta and derives the rotation matrix
   by projecting the new x and y axes onto the original ones.

Which one of them is the correct derivation? What significance does each method have?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unclear. The two methods are essentially the same and reach the same correct conclusion. Neither is more correct.

Comment: What is the significance of each method? On what basis are they essentially the same?

Comment: There are 2 approaches to geometric transformations. Tn the "alias" approach. we think of the points as being fixed and the coordinate axes as moving. In the "alibi" approach, we think of the coordinate axes as being fixed and the ooints as moving. Each approach has its partisans. Whether the names reflect the criminal propensities of geometers is a question best discussed on some other forum.

Comment: There is no particular significance. They reach the same conclusion with elementary reasoning about the same geometry. The words differ some, as you would expect.

Comment: @P.Lawrence That makes it clear to me. Thanks for the comments, everyone.